# UiTests - Xcode stop showing failed tests result

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcuitest

I'm running UiTests with XCUITests using Xcode 11 and for some reason when a test failed, there are no attachments or any explanation at the Report navigator section in Xcode.

On previous versions of Xcode, I could see the screenshots/functions that used for the test/Where the test failed/etc...

Is there any way to fix this? I can't know why the tests are failing

[image]

I've tried to reinstall Xcode/install previous versions of Xcode

No code needed here.

Comment: what do you see in log? (bottom panel)

Comment: You should probably find and open `*.xcresult` file in `Derived Data`.

Comment: @KirilS.
The logs end with the AssertFailure line 
"t =   128.45s Assertion Failure: ClassName.swift:128: XCTAssertTrue failed"
I don't find any information in the logs that point on screenshots/snapshot issues.

Comment: @SmartMonkey
Can you explain more clearly what do you mean, please?

Comment: So in `ClassName.swift:128` there's `XCTAssertTrue ` assertion that fails. Prior to that you should see in log what test was doing at the time. And if you run it interactively you should see whether the test is on the right screen at the moment of the failure, and so on. Besides that, very little can be said based on info you provided

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your test plan configurations & ensure that the UI Testing -> Automatic Screenshots is not set to "Off" and "Attachments" -> "Attachments" is not set to "Off" either.

If both are set to on for the test plan configuration you're running, you could try running my company's tool xcparse to see if the attachments are there but Xcode is somehow failing to show (but that seems unlikely).  https://github.com/ChargePoint/xcparse